# Woher kommt "Freunde des schlechten Geschmacks"?

Tags: etymology, idiom, colloquial

Gibt es irgendeine "Quelle" für die Wendung "(meine lieben) Freunde des schlechten Geschmacks"?r

Comment: Ich denke "Freunde der/des ...." ist als allgemeine oder auch ironisch gemeinte Anrede durchaus verbreitet und kann mit allem möglichen verwendet werden (Freunde der Nacht, Freunde des Motorsports, Freunde des guten Geschmacks, ...). Ich sehe da jetzt keine Besonderheit in diesem Spruch, so dass er eine bestimmte Quelle haben müsste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hierfür eine eindeutige historische Quelle zu finden, dürfte unmöglich sein.

Die Freunde des **guten** Geschmacks sind allerdings schon etwas älter. Siehe z.B. http://zs.thulb.uni-jena.de/receive/jportal_jparticle_00018940

Dieser Wendung dürften sich vor allem gehobene Kreise (oder solche, die sich dafür hielten) verschiedenster Coleur bedient haben, um sich vom Rest der Gesellschaft vermeintlich abzugrenzen.

In der Folge könnte "Freunde des **schlechten** Geschmacks" als eine (selbst)ironische Antwort aller "Betroffenen" entstanden sein, um wiederum auf diese Weise ein Zusammengehörigkeitsgefühl zu erzeugen.

Comment: Noch ältere "Freunde des guten Geschmacks" [aus 1763](http://books.google.de/books?id=1Nc9AAAAcAAJ&dq=%22Freunde%20des%20guten%20Geschmacks%22&pg=PP10#v=onepage&q=%22Freunde%20des%20guten%20Geschmacks%22&f=false), wohl angelehnt an Voltaires "Tempel des guten Geschmacks" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Die Fragestellung ist wohl besser für "echte" Sprichwörter (wie z. B. *etwas jdm. in die Schuhe schieben*) geeignet. Diese Phrase hingegen ist nur geringfügig sprichwörtlich – einzig "ungewöhnlich" an ihr ist, dass Personen mit etwas (und nicht mit jemandem) befreundet sind.

Um also die Herkunft zu klären, müsste man herausfinden, wann zum ersten Mal eine solche Entfremdung des Freundesbegriffes stattgefunden hat. Dieser Schritt scheint aber recht naheliegend (oft im nicht sarkastischen Sinne, z. B. Freunde des Motorsports, des Lesens), was die Findung einer unikalen Quelle äußerst schwer gestaltet. Fest steht, dass (zumindest) schon Goethe Ähnliches kannte:

> **Papagey:** Ich bin ein erklärter Freund von Nachtigallen, Lerchen und anderen Singvögeln.
>
> [(Johann Wolfgang von Goethe: Die Vögel – Kapitel 2)](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/die-v-5646/2)

Außerdem noch gefunden:

- Freunde des Bestehenden [(1841/42)](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/die-parlamentarische-periode-des-b-372/1)
- Freunde des Vergnügens [(18. Jh.)](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/physiologie-des-geschmacks-7230/38)