# Translation of "Internet portal for fans of unstable/labile balance"

Tags: translation

I have to translate the sentence "Internet portal for fans of unstable/labile balance". This is the name of a link that will lead to a web site intended for bicycle and cycling fans.

Is the: "Internetportal für Fans von labilen Gleichgewicht" the correct translation ?

Comment: Is there a humorous connotation intended in the original sentence?

Comment: I think I would just go for "Freunde der Ballance".... the "labilen" doesn't pull the whole thing more toward "biking". Actually, it rather pulls it away from that, in my opinion. "Ballance" for me does imply some possible imbalance already so adding a "labil" to it makes it really wobbly .. which is not what I associate with biking.

Comment: Yes, humorous connotation is intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the word `Fan` is from English origin and usually found in combination with proper nouns, I'm not sure which case has to be used after it. Your translation sounds wrong to me. I would go with Dativ (`labilem Gleichgewicht`) but...

... for the humorous connotation it would be most appropriate to align it to the well known phrase [Freunde des guten Geschmacks](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15577):

> Internetportal für Freunde des labilen Gleichgewichts